# Import of PEM certificate chain and key to Java Keystore

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509, keystore

There are plenty of resources out there about this topic, but none I found which covers this slightly special case.

I have 4 files;

- privatekey.pem
- certificate.pem
- intermediate_rapidssl.pem
- ca_geotrust_global.pem

And I wish to import them into a fresh keystore.

Some site suggest to use DER-format, and import them one by one, but this failed because the key is not recognized.

Another site suggested a special "ImportKey"-class to run for import, and this worked until I saw that the chain is broken. I.e. the chain length on the certificate is 1, ignoring the intermediate and ca.

Some sites suggest PKCS7, but I can't even get a chain from that. Other suggest PKCS12 format, but as far as my tests go that failed as well for getting the whole chain.

Any advice or hints are much welcome.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This may not be perfect, but I had some notes on my use of `keytool` that I've modified for your scenario.

1. Import a root or intermediate CA certificate to an existing Java keystore:

   ```
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file ca_geotrust_global.pem -keystore yourkeystore.jks
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file intermediate_rapidssl.pem -keystore yourkeystore.jks
   ```
2. Combine the certificate and private key into one file before importing.

   ```
   cat certificate.pem privatekey.pem > combined.pem
   ```

   This should result in a file resembling the below format.

   > BEGIN CERTIFICATE
   >   ...
   >   END CERTIFICATE
   >   BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY
   >   ...
   >   END RSA PRIVATE KEY
3. Import a signed primary certificate & key to an existing Java keystore:

   ```
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias yourdomain -file combined.pem -keystore yourkeystore.jks
   ```

Comment: What version of keytool allows you to chain like this? This syntax gives "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <root> already exists" with both -import and -importcert

Comment: Hard to say, exactly. But given the year/month it was likely to be Java 6? (No idea the minor release.) What version are you using? The error reads like  the problem could be with the keystore itself. (`alias <root> already exists`) Can you try with a new, empty keystore?

Comment: Keytool will not let me import a certificate using an already existing alias 'root'. But i think it was a typo.

Interesting to note that keytool creates a chain for your certificate itself when it finds the signers' certificates in the keystore (under any alias). 
 
Java tool ["Portecle"](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) is handy for managing the java keystore.

Comment: Keytool doesn't work like this, and doesn't allow you to import an alias more than once as described.  (And yes, I've tried).  See senajqerib's answer below for something that works properly.

Comment: It's a three year old answer. It is entirely possible that things have changed, but I assure you it worked (or was close to working as I indicated it may not be perfect) as of Feb. 2013. Please feel free to submit an edit or flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: And what if you have multiple domains?

Comment: In step 1 you've given the same alias: `root` to two different CAs.  This alias should be applied to the `ca_geotrust_global.pem` cert only, I think and you can alias the other one e.g. `intermediary` or similar.

Comment: This doesn't work! You need to generate a PKCS12 store first, and then import it using the keytool cli. See: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-and-private-key

Comment: Perhaps that's what I meant by importing to an *existing Java keystore* in step 1. I don't know because I wrote it 7 years ago. Please feel free to add your own answer with an missing or additional helpful steps.

Answer (score 57):

Concatenate all *.pem files into one pem file, like all.pem
Then create keystore in p12 format with private key + all.pem

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private.key -in all.pem -name test -out test.p12
```

Then export p12 into jks

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore test.jks
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is the only complete and correct answer.  As you suggested, it's far easier to just concatenate together the certs into one file.

Comment: This worked like a treat for me!! I used these instructions to convert a chain of keys used in nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example repository to talk to a Java based TLS server. Thanks a million!

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Does "all.pem" also contain the private key?

Comment: JustAGuy, all.pem does not contain private.key. Private key file (above: private.key) is stored in a separate file.

Comment: How to get the private.key file?, I donwloaded the .pem chain file from the website I'm trying to connect using firefox explorer

Answer (score 11):

keytool doesn't provide a way to import certificate + private key from a single (combined) file, as proposed above. It runs fine, but only certificate is imported, while private key is ignored. You can check it by `keytool -list -v -keystore yourkeystore.jks` - yourdomain entry type is TrustedCertEntry, not PrivateKeyEntry.

So to solve the initial problem, one should first create a PKCS#12 keystore using openssl (or similar tool), then import the keystore with `keytool -importkeystore`.